# Chartjs-adapter-luxon doesn't give the right labels

Tags: javascript, chart.js, luxon

I'm making a line chart in sveltekit, using the `svelte-chartjs` package. The data for this chart is a set of timestamps, so I have to use a date adapter for chart.js.

The adapter I'm using is `chartjs-adapter-luxon`, and it seems to work, it spaces everything out correctly, except it has the wrong labels.

The labels are all showing one specific day: `Jan 20, 1970`, but my data has timestamps from several weeks in it, and none of them are from 1970. It's also suspicious that they're so close to the Unix epoch.

I can't figure it out, please help

My relevant code:

```
<script>
export let data
    import { Line } from 'svelte-chartjs';
    import 'luxon'
    import 'chartjs-adapter-luxon'
    import {
        Chart,
        Tooltip,
        Legend,
        BarElement,
        CategoryScale,
        LinearScale,
        LineElement,
        PointElement,
        TimeScale,
    } from 'chart.js';
    Chart.register(
        Tooltip,
        Legend,
        BarElement,
        CategoryScale,
        LineElement,
        PointElement,
        LinearScale,
        TimeScale,
    );
    let graphdata = graph()
    let graphoptions = {
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    unit: 'day',
                    displayFormats: {
                        second: 'MMM d, yyyy'
                    }
                },
                adapters: {
                    date: {
                        zone: 'UTC+6'
                    }
                },
            }
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
    }
    function graph() {
        if (data.graph) {
            let labels = []
            for (let i = 0; i < data.graph.timestamp.length; i++) {
                let timestamp = data.graph.timestamp[i]
                const myDateTime = new Date(timestamp * 1000)
                const myDateTimeISO = myDateTime.toISOString()
                labels.push(new Date(myDateTimeISO))
            }
            let graphdata = {
                labels: data.graph.timestamp,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Followers',
                        data: data.graph.followers,
                        backgroundColor: ["rgb(30 58 138 / 1)"],
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        borderColor: "#e5e7eb",
                        hoverBackgroundColor: ["rgb(30 58 138 / 1)"],
                        hoverBorderColor: "#e5e7eb",
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Following',
                        data: data.graph.following,
                        backgroundColor: ["#818cf8"],
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        borderColor: "#e5e7eb",
                        hoverBackgroundColor: ["#818cf8"],
                        hoverBorderColor: "#e5e7eb",
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Posts',
                        data: data.graph.posts,
                        backgroundColor: ["rgb(253 224 71 / 1)"],
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        borderColor: "#e5e7eb",
                        hoverBackgroundColor: ["rgb(253 224 71 / 1)"],
                        hoverBorderColor: "#e5e7eb",
                    },
                ],
            };
            return graphdata
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }
</script>
<Line data={graphdata} options={graphoptions} />
```

Comment: In your code I see that you are setting labels with labels: data.graph.timestamp which doesn't seem to an array of epoch

Comment: data.graph.timestamp is an array of unix dates

Comment: I think this is the reason why you see Jan, 20 1970. In your sample you created the labels array transforming unix time in epoch but it seems you are not using it. Furthermore I don't think "data.labels" can be set with an array of Dates, I think only strings